# Find all graphs with valency sequence $(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)$

Tags: graph-theory

Test the following sequences using to see if they are graphical or
not: (if they are graphical draw an exemplar graph having that valency sequence)

Comment: The title and the question don’t agree; are you interested in finding **one** such graph, or in finding **all** of them?

Comment: What following sequences? Can you do something so the title and the body agree, and make sense?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by considering the vertex of degree 4.  Draw it and the 4 neighbors.  What can you do next?

Answer (score 3):

There is [an algorithm](http://faculty.cbu.ca/jpreen/valseq.pdf) to easily verify valency sequences.

Enumering all possible graphs is a slightly more difficult problem. As there are only a few graphs with 6 nodes you can however figure out that there are only 2 possible graphs with that sequence: (you can modify the algorithm to give you all possible graphs)

Graphs 1 and 2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for finding that page that I created back in 2003, I forgot I ever did it! This year I was teaching my course again and this time I made up a Maple worksheet (using the GraphTheory package which is available since Maple 13). It makes a list of all simple graphs with any given valency sequence, and is available here: http://faculty.capebretonu.ca/jpreen/410112w1.mws

Comment: @jp26 neat to see that you are using stackexchange too. I found your description of the algorithm very straight forward and easy to understand, so I linked it.