# Counting non-isomorphic connected graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many non-isomorphic connected graphs with N vertices in which X vertices have degree of A (and maybe Y vertices have degree of B)?

How should one approach this type of question? Tried drawing it, but it just seems to be too much of a hustle considering number of vertices is actually 11.

EDIT: Well N is 11, X is 2, A is 3, Y 9 and B is 2, if it helps explaining.

Comment: Start with a lower order, and enumerate the graphs of that type.  Then look up that sequence in [OEIS](http://oeis.org). If you are seriously looking at graphs, get Nauty.

Comment: Think dumbbell.

Comment: @EdPegg The problem is that I don't always have sequence calculator at hand, so I'd need a direct way of finding the solution for 11. Chris Godsil I didn't really catch what you mean.

Comment: Your general question is much more difficult than your specific question.  For this simple case, draw two dots and join them, then figure out all the ways to connect the loose ends.  Then count the distinct ways to add 9 more dots to the drawn lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself which combinations of degree vertices one vertex of largest degree is joined to (for you the largest degree is 3 and there are 2 choices for its neighbours, either all 2s or two 2s and the other 3).

You can then repeat this procedure for both the new sequences until you have known sequences (all graphs with a degree sequence consisting of 1s and 2s are unions of paths and cycles).

Then you rebuild your graph in all possible ways and check for duplicates. For your question you then need to ensure that they are connected.

The general procedure for small graphs is outlined at this question, note that valency is another word for degree: [Find all graphs with valency sequence $(4, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151984/find-all-graphs-with-valency-sequence-4-2-2-2-1-1?rq=1)